# MVC ajax dynamic dropdownlist

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

Are there examples of using ajax for dropdownlist.  I want to pre-load the dropdownlist so it can be selected from, but also want to be able to key into the dropdownlist field to search and have it list items matching.

Please provide links to examples, or post example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use very powerful plugin: [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plagin.
Example for you case:

```
$('choices input').autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/autocomplete/Controller"+request.term+"/",
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function(){$('ul.chzn-results').empty();},
      success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
          $('ul.chzn-results').append('<li class="active-result">' + item.name + '</li>');
        }));
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Auto Complete functionality of J-Query See the below link for its sample implementation..

http://basiccodeexample.blogspot.in/search?q=AutoComplete

Or You can use datalist html5 tag find the reference in below link

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist